# No module Found error in Linux but Works fine in Windows

Tags: linux, python

I am trying to run a Program that I coded in Python in Windows environment 
When I am trying to copy the program and running it in Linux(Debian),
It won't work,

It is giving the following error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BlackBox.py", line 26, in <module>
    from BB_Files import BB_Expand
ImportError: No module named BB_Files
```

Despite the presence of the file BB_Expand inside BB_Files folder, I am still getting the error.

I have also tried appending the path of my current directories in Python,

```
sys.path.append("/home/pe/Desktop/AES")
# Sub-Folders of AES are also accessible
sys.path.append("/home/pe/Desktop/AES/BB_Files")
```

But Still no Luck,

This is the File Structure,

```
/home/pe/Desktop/AES/Main.py
/home/pe/Desktop/AES/BB_Files
/home/pe/Desktop/AES/BB_Files/BB_Days.py
/home/pe/Desktop/AES/BB_Files/BB_Expand.py
/home/pe/Desktop/AES/BB_Files/BB_Steps.py
```

this is the output of `ls -l` command,

```
drwxrwx--x 4 pe users  4096 Oct 26 21:43 BB_Files
-rw-rw---- 1 pe users 15284 Oct 26 22:04 Main.py
```

This is some initial code in the file,

```
import sys    # sys.argv ; sys.path, sys.exit
import os
import hashlib
import struct # Interpret strings as packed binary data
import getopt # for Runtime arguments
import time
from datetime import date

# Append Paths from where the Files would be Imported.
sys.path.append("/home/pe/Desktop/AES")
# Sub-Folders of AES are also accessible
sys.path.append("/home/pe/Desktop/AES/BB_Files")
# Sub-Fodlers of BB_Files are also accessible now (Tables)
from BB_Files import BB_Expand
from BB_Files import BB_Steps
from BB_Files import BB_Days
```

This is the line giving an error,

```
from BB_Files import BB_Expand
```

The program doesn't run after this line because the Python couldn't find this Module.

The same code works absolutely fine in Windows.

could anyone please help me out with this ?

Comment: Could you give us a minimal working example of the script? Does the user running the script have read access to the relevant folders?

Comment: Hello, I have also tried to run the code as a root, 
The code supposed to read a python file from the folder B'B_Files', I have directly copied the Code folder from Windows to Linux through Network Sharing so I am not sure what permissions are required for the folder.

Comment: I understand, which is why I asked to see some code, it is difficult to guess otherwise. Please show us the lines that load the modules, and `ls -l` output of the relevant folders.

Comment: Thank you, I have added all the details you have asked for, please see the question again @terdon

Comment: Yes I am running it as pe, but 'sudo python Main.py' also gives the same error.

Comment: It looks like python is expecting a module but finding a folder instead. Does it work if you import the file name directly? Something like `from BB_Expand import BB_Expand` (assuming the BB_Expand method is in a file called BB_Expand.py).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a (possible empty) file called `__init__.py` in your BB_Files folder. From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages):

> The __init__.py files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, __init__.py can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package